# Suggestions are not working in actions on google

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I create a chat bot using dialogflow and actions on google library. In the back-end code I have created function including if else. I added new suggestions in the "else if". That are not display in the actions on google simulator.Another suggestions are working. Only that time it is not displayed. Please  give me some instructions for fixed that.
this is my code:

```
'use strict';
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {
   dialogflow,
   Suggestions,
   Carousel,
   Image,
   Table,
   List,
} = require('actions-on-google');
const app = dialogflow({debug: true});

// Constants for list and carousel selection
const Order_Food = 'order food';
const Extra_Product = 'extra product';
const Spa_Reservation = 'spa reservation';
const Restaurant_Booking = 'restaurant booking';

app.intent('user.provide_room_number', (conv) => {
    conv.ask('Great! I can help you with the following. Please select 
from the options below.');
//conv.ask(new Suggestions('Order Food', 'Extra Product', 
  'Restaurant', 'Spa'));
// Create a carousel
conv.ask(new Carousel({
    items: {
        // Add the first item to the carousel
        [Order_Food]: {
          synonyms: [
            'order food',
            'food',
          ],
          title: 'Food',
          description: 'Can order some food',
          image: new Image({
            url: 'http://www.restauranteelpalacete.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Online-Food-Ordering.jpg',
            alt: 'Food',
          }),
        },
          // Add third item to the carousel
          [Spa_Reservation]: {
            synonyms: [
              'spa',
              'spa reservation',
            ],
            title: 'Spa Reservation',
            description: 'Can put the reservation on the spa.',
            image: new Image({
              url: 'https://res.klook.com/images/fl_lossy.progressive,q_65/c_fill,w_1295,h_720,f_auto/w_80,x_15,y_15,g_south_west,l_klook_water/activities/kykzulvt1t71kwhnmkik/OasisSpa.jpg',
              alt: 'Spa',
            }),
          },
          // Add fourth item to the carousel
          [Restaurant_Booking]: {
            synonyms: [
              'restaurant',
              'restaurant booking',
            ],
            title: 'Restaurant',
            description: 'Can put the reservation on the Restaurant.',
            image: new Image({
              url: 'https://cdn-image.foodandwine.com/sites/default/files/1501607996/opentable-scenic-restaurants-marine-room-FT-BLOG0818.jpg',
              alt: 'Restaurant',
            }),
          },
    },
}));
```

});

```
 app.intent('actions_intent_OPTION-handler', (conv, params, option) => {
 // Get the user's selection
 // Compare the user's selections to each of the item's keys
 if (!option) {
  conv.ask('You did not select any item from the list or carousel');
} else if (option === 'order food') {
  conv.ask(new SimpleResponse({speech:"Absolutely, have you decided what you like or you could go through the in room dinning menu. \n Do you need order Food.?",text:"Absolutely, have you decided what you like or you could go through the in room dinning menu. Do you need order Food.?"}));
  conv.ask(new Suggestions(["Ok", "Done", "Thanks"]));
} else if (option === 'spa reservation') {
  conv.ask(new Suggestions('Yes I need Spa.'));
  conv.ask(`We have an excellent Spa that offer exquisite treatment packages. You can select one of the options. We have quite a few free slots today. Do you need information about that.`);

} else if (option === 'restaurant booking') {
  conv.ask(`We have some dining options for you today. Do you want more information. `);
  conv.ask(new Suggestions('I need restaurant.'));
} else {
  conv.ask('You selected an unknown item from the list, or carousel');
}
```

});

Comment: can you check at action on google sdk what is the response you are getting in for this intent from firebase. You have to debug the code.

Answer (score 0):

You should design your conversation bot more efficiently.In second elseif condition, after a suggestion no further conversation should happen in an intent.Suggestion are for triggering intent. For your case best scenario would be to create a follow up intent. 
Suggestion is not appearing in conversation because, in every rich response at least one simple response should be present. Try below code. Hope this helps you.

```
conv.ask(new SimpleResponse({speech:"Absolutely, have you decided what you like or you could go through the in room dinning menu. \n Do you need order Food.?",text:"Absolutely, have you decided what you like or you could go through the in room dinning menu. Do you need order Food.?"}));
conv.ask(new Suggestions(["Ok", "Done", "Thanks"]));
```

Comment: Thank u R.Sarkar. But it's not working. That code is included at the actions_intent_OPTION handler for the carousel.